# How to execute a set of Python scripts at Ubuntu Server from Android Client app and return the result to client app

Tags: android, python, linux, ubuntu, client-server

I am using an Android application as a client and an Ubuntu PC as a server for my Project. I am sending a video file from my android client to server. After that at Server I have to execute a set of Python scripts and then result will be sent as a textual data to Android client. 

**I have already made an Android app which sends video from android device to the Ubuntu Server which is a Xampp server (suggest any other server if you feel that is better), but now after receiving the file at Server side I want to process it by executing the set of Python scripts automatically at Server and return the result back. Is anyone can help me who can tell How to do this part?**

Answer (score 0):

If you owe the server or can modify API, used for uploading video, problem is solvable on the server side. Simply return result of python scripts as response to upload request. For detailed answer, please provide more information about server software.

If you cant't modify the server code or want control execution from Android, I recommend you consider about using `ssh` for that purpose. As instance, there are some 3rd party libraries, that support ssh communication, such as [hierynomus/sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/).

Example of ssh communication:

```
final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
ssh.loadKnownHosts();

ssh.connect("your.server.host");
try {
    ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    final Session session = ssh.startSession();
    try {
        final Command cmd = session.exec("python script.py");
        String response = IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString();
        cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Yes the server is owned by me as I'm creating it at local machine temporally for development. And for the upload service I am using this library : https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Comment: I'm not familiar with XAMPP, and can't guide how to override uploading request and sent a responce back. Not sure if it possible in XAMPP at all. I suggest you to ask new question relative to xampp.

Comment: Can you suggest any other server in which you are familiar??

Comment: The simplest way: create your own standalone handler for uploading videos using `Flask` or `Tornado` frameworks, since you already use python. New workflow will be User uploads video -> New handler place it to Xampp -> New handler execute scripts -> Send result as response. Android program will operate to new handler only, it's like a facade to Xampp. Very simple and could be done in a few hours.